# Assigning variable in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, kubectl

I have a part of script that doesn't return anything in the 'token' variable and not sure what is wrong here.

```
kubectl exec -it $pod_name -n <namespace> /bin/bash <<EOF

# Step 3: Get the token and exit the bash shell
echo "Step 3: Retrieving token from pod: $pod_name"
token=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
echo
echo "retrieved token: $token"
exit
EOF

echo "retrieved token: $token"
```

I checked other answers that suggest removing spaces and such but it didn't help

Comment: `token` should become the content of the file `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`. Most likely, the file is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was the solution:

```
echo "Step 3: Retrieving token from pod: $pod_name"
token=$(kubectl exec $pod_name -n <namespace-name> -- cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
```